# Elasticsearch completion field with jdbc river

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using JDBC River to load data:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type": "jdbc",
        "jdbc": {
        "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
            "user": "root",
            "password": "root",
            "sql": "SELECT TAD.ID AS _id, TAD.APP_NAME AS appName FROM TOPIC_APP_DETAILS TAD ",
            "index": "app_index",
            "type": "app_type",
            "mappings": {
            "app_type": {
                "properties": {
                    "appName": {
                        "type": "completion"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I execute below query getting **ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.CompletionFieldMapper]**;

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/app_index/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
    "app-suggest" : {
        "text" : "cri",
            "completion" : {
            "field" : "appName"
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by creating my own data loader class to fetch data from database for indexing into Elasticsearch.

**Getting data from database.**

String empName = rs.getString("EMP_NAME");
String empId = rs.getInt("EMP_ID");

**Load data into Elasticsearch**

XContentBuilder appBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
appBuilder.field("empName", empName);
getClient().prepareIndex("Index", "Type", String.valueOf(empId)).setSource(appBuilder).execute().actionGet();